# How to set value for the specific range of a C array using std:fill

Tags: c++, c++11

How can i set the value only for specific range of some array and not starting from zero. the following code invokes compile error:

```
#include <algorithm>;

bool SomeBoolArray[100];
std::fill(SomeBoolArray[50], SomeBoolArray[50] + 10, true);
```

following form invokes compiler error too.

```
std::fill(SomeBoolArray[50], SomeBoolArray[60], true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::fill` requires iterators, or iterator-likes, like pointers:

```
std::fill(SomeBoolArray + 50, SomeBoolArray + 60, true);
```

Comment: The OP can also write this as `std::fill(&SomeBoolArray[50], &SomeBoolArray[50] + 10, true);`